# How to keep the divider in a div in sync with the top arrow of the div always even if the content changes in the div using react and css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want the divider inside the div to be just under the top arrow the div. Right now I have it something like below:

[image: example image]

below is my code,

```js
    function Parent() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="flex_wrapper">
                    <button> click </button>
                    <div className="box">
                        <BoxContent />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    function BoxContent() {
        return (
            <div className="box_content_wrapper">
                {true && (
                    <>
                        <Available />
                        <div className="spacing" />
                        <span>
                            Available <br />
                            <span className="sub_text">some text</span>
                        </span>
                        <div className="divider" />
                    </>
                )}
                <Available />
                <div className="spacing" />
                <span>
                    Available <br />
                    <span className="sub_text">some text</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }

    function Available() {
        return (
            <div className="view">
                <span>10</span> //when i change these values to any big number also i want the divider 
                 //and the arrow to be 
                //in just below each other
                <span>/100</span> //when i change these values to any big number also i want the divider 
                //and the arrow to be in just below each other
            </div>
        ); 
    }
```

below is the css

```css
    .wrapper {
        height: 40px;
        display: flex;
        z-index: 4;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
        position: relative;
    }

    .flex_wrapper {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .box {
        padding: 16px;
        height: 61px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        top: 72px;
        left: 35px;
    }

    .box::after {
        content: "";
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: black;
        top: -4px;
        left: 141px;
        border-left: 8px solid;
        border-left-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
        border-top: 8px solid transparent;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    }

    .box_content_wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .view {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: baseline;
        margin-top: 8px;
    }

    .sub_text {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .spacing {
        width: 8px;
    }

    .divider {
        height: 37px;
        margin-left: 16px;
        margin-right: 16px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
     }
```

You can find the working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bush-mj7lz?file=/src/App.js

I am not sure how to keep both the divider and arrow in sync even when the data meaning in the Available component even if i change the span content some large numbers, the divider and arrow should be just below each other.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-darkness-kzjys).

The only applied changes are the following:

1. Added the CSS rule `position: relative;` at the element `.divider`.
2. Changed the parent of the pseudo-selector `:after` (the one that concerns the top arrow). Now the arrow has the element `.divider` as a parent. In this way, the arrow will always remain above the divider, no matter how long is the value inside the content (please check the picture below).
3. Finally, I have adapted the top and left position of the arrow element (`.divider:after`), so it will always stay on top of the container and centered aligned concerning the divider (the `left` value comes from the calculation `0 - width of the arrow / 2`). The new values are the following:
   `top: -32px; left: -4px;`

[image: codesandbox screenshot]

Below you can find all the modified CSS:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  position: relative;
}

.flex_wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  padding: 16px;
  height: 61px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 72px;
  left: 35px;
}

.box_content_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.view {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.sub_text {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.spacing {
  width: 8px;
}

.divider {
  height: 37px;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
}

.divider::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  top: -32px;
  left: -4px;
  border-left: 8px solid;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton. but this would move the arrow away from the click button. if click button is say the click button has margin-left: 165px. so the arrow, divider should always be right in center of the click button.